# MySQL - if row is duplicate, return only the first one

Tags: mysql, sql, rows

I have a MySQL table "results" which has the following fields:

```
id (PK, AI), user_id (FK), date, score, time
```

I want to be able to query this table so that it sorts and returns the fields in order of score (descending order) followed by time (ascending order).  So something like:

```
SELECT * FROM results ORDER BY score DESC, time ASC.
```

However, after this sorting, if more than one row has the same `user_id`, I only want to include the highest row.

How would I do this?

Comment: You want to include the _highest_ row by `time`, `score`, or `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `not exists`:

```
SELECT *
FROM results r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from results r2 where r2.user_id = r.user_id and r2.id > r.id)
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

This will work best with an index on `results(user_id, id)`.

Comment: I receive this 'Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'r2.id' in 'where clause'' :s

Comment: @Bhav . . . That doesn't make sense.  Your question explicitly states that `results` has an `id` column.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: `SELECT user_id, max(score), time FROM results GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY score DESC;`

Select id and highest score per `user_id` via `max()` and `Group By`. Then order the records by score descending.

EDIT: If you need the time for the user-score and there is only one entry with the same score you can use a subselect to get this time:

```
SELECT user_id, max(score), (
    SELECT max(time) 
    FROM results AS r2 
    WHERE r2.user_id = r1.user_id
        AND r2.score = max(r1.score)
) AS time 
FROM results AS r1
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Comment: @JohnBupit Yeah, I've replaced id with user_id (twice).

Comment: @MartinSeitl Having used this, it doesn't seem to solve my problem.  The query returns the maximum score for each user_id but it doesn't return the time associated with the maximum score.  It returns the first time for each user_id.

Comment: is it possible that one user_id has multiple scores with the same value? if not, a subselect would be possible.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. I think I've managed to come up with a solution for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get something working at the moment.

```
SELECT user_id, score, time 
FROM results T
WHERE T.score = (
SELECT MAX(T2.score)
FROM results T2
WHERE T2.user_id = T.user_id
)
ORDER BY score DESC, time ASC;
```